# Range.find is not finding date from Date object

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, power-automate, office-scripts

I have created a script in excel (typescript) that works all fine locally but when I run it in the Power Automate Cloud I receive the following error: `Cannot read property 'getOffsetRange' of undefined clientRequestId`.

The purpose of the script is to find, in a table with dates, the date corresponding to the first day of the current month and write in the cell next to it.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // Get the active worksheet.
    let sheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Blad1");
    let escp_tab = sheet.getTable("table_name");

    // takes the day of today
    let date = new Date();
    // get the first day of the month
    let firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
    // format the date in DD/MM/YYYY and makes it a string
    const formattedDate = firstDay.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {
        day: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', year: 'numeric'
    }).replace(/ /g, '/');

    //sets the range of find to the coulmn Year of the table
    let range = escp_tab.getColumnByName("Year").getRange();
    //find in the specified range the first cell with value formattedDate    
    let cellToFind = range.find(formattedDate, { completeMatch: true });
    //define the cellToFill as the one on the same row and one column to the right of cellToFind
    let cellToFill = cellToFind.getOffsetRange(0,1);
    //sets the value of the cellToFill
    cellToFill.setValue("250");
}
```

I have already tried to save the excel file again or create a new one from scratch, but none of these two solution seems to be fixing the bug.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the reason your code is failing is the `range.find()` part. When I run your code I get this value for the `formattedDate` in the console `01/04/2023`. When I write the value to a cell on the Excel worksheet, I get this value `1/4/2023`. It looks like Excel is removing the 0s when the value is written to the sheet. So the value you're searching for is likely different than the value you have in the table. Since the value isn't found, undefined is returned. So that's the reason you're getting your error.

Since number formats can be finicky, it's best not to use them with something like `find`. A better solution is to use the serial value of the date and check against the serial value in the `year` column. The serial value will remain constant regardless of what the formatting is. You would have to convert the date in your `formattedDate` to an Excel serial date. The easy way to do this is to write the value somewhere in any empty cell on any worksheet. After that's done, you can read the value of the date and store the serial value in a variable. After you do that, you can get the row count, column count, and values in the year column. Then you can use loops to iterate through the values and check against the serial value. If you find a match, you can use the loop variable values to write to the offset range.

You can see how to do this using the code below. The cell I used to write the `formattedDate` to is cell E1 on the Blad1 worksheet:

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // Get the active worksheet.
    let sheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Blad1");
    let escp_tab = sheet.getTable("table_name");

    // takes the day of today
    let date = new Date();
    // get the first day of the month
    let firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
    // format the date in DD/MM/YYYY and makes it a string
    const formattedDate = firstDay.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {
        day: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', year: 'numeric'
    }).replace(/ /g, '/');

    //sets the range of find to the coulmn Year of the table
    let range = escp_tab.getColumnByName("Year").getRange();

    let serial_cell = sheet.getRange("E1")
    serial_cell.setValue(formattedDate)
    let serial_value = serial_cell.getValue()
    serial_cell.clear()

    let rowCount = range.getRowCount()
    let colCount = range.getColumnCount()

    let range_values = range.getValues()

    for (let i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < colCount; j++) {
            if (range_values[i][j] == serial_value) {
                sheet.getCell(i,j).getOffsetRange(0,1).setValue(250)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sidney! Thanks a lot for the suggestion.
I tried you code but it's not printing anything in excel. I debugged it and it identifies the right row and column (so it finds the value) but the 'sheet.getCell(i, j).getOffsetRange(0, 1).setValue(250)' is not working.

Comment: With a closer look I noticed that it is printing but not in the right position. This code is not considering the relative position of the table in the page. I need to manually correct the i and j indexes to the real position of the table. Is there a more elegant way that I can achieve this?